# Count of most popular words in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

I use a csv data file containing movie data. In this dataset there is a column named plot_keywords.I want to find the 10 or 20 most popular keywords ,the number of times they show up and plotting them in a bar chart.To be more specific i copied 2 instances as they show up when i print the dataframe

9                        blood|book|love|potion|professor

18              blackbeard|captain|pirate|revenge|soldier

I open the csv file as a pandas DataFrame.Here is the code i have so far

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
pd.Series(' '.join(data['plot_keywords']).lower().split()).value_counts()[:10]
```

None of other posts have helped me so far
Thanks in advance

https://www.kaggle.com/deepmatrix/imdb-5000-movie-dataset/kernels

Answer (score 20):

Here is a **NLTK solution**, which ignores English stopwords (for example: `in`, `on`, `of`, `the`, etc.):

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import nltk

top_N = 10

df = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/imdb-5000-movie-dataset.zip',
                 usecols=['movie_title','plot_keywords'])

txt = df.plot_keywords.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').str.cat(sep=' ')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(txt)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
words_except_stop_dist = nltk.FreqDist(w for w in words if w not in stopwords) 

print('All frequencies, including STOPWORDS:')
print('=' * 60)
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
print(rslt)
print('=' * 60)

rslt = pd.DataFrame(words_except_stop_dist.most_common(top_N),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency']).set_index('Word')

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

rslt.plot.bar(rot=0)
```

Output:

```
All frequencies, including STOPWORDS:
============================================================
     Word  Frequency
0      in        339
1  female        301
2   title        289
3  nudity        259
4    love        248
5      on        240
6  school        238
7  friend        228
8      of        222
9     the        212
============================================================
```

[image]

**Pandas solution**, which uses stopwords from NLTK module:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import nltk

top_N = 10

df = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/imdb-5000-movie-dataset.zip',
                 usecols=['movie_title','plot_keywords'])

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
# RegEx for stopwords
RE_stopwords = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(stopwords))
# replace '|'-->' ' and drop all stopwords
words = (df.plot_keywords
           .str.lower()
           .replace([r'\|', RE_stopwords], [' ', ''], regex=True)
           .str.cat(sep=' ')
           .split()
)

# generate DF out of Counter
rslt = pd.DataFrame(Counter(words).most_common(top_N),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency']).set_index('Word')
print(rslt)

# plot
rslt.plot.bar(rot=0, figsize=(16,10), width=0.8)
```

Output:

```
        Frequency
Word
female        301
title         289
nudity        259
love          248
school        238
friend        228
police        210
male          205
death         195
sex           192
```